Copy User Defined Fields from Purchase Order Header to Purchase Receipt Header
Hi I am trying to copy the purchase order user defined fields to the purchase receipt when the enter PO receipt button is clicked. I have tried the below methods but no  copying occurs.
namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PO.POReceiptEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
  
protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<POReceipt> e)
{
    POReceipt receipt = e.Row; // Find current POReceipt record
    if (receipt == null) return;

    // Fetch the related POOrder record using the PO Receipt's PO Number and PO Type
    POOrder order = SelectFrom<POOrder>
                    .Where<POOrder.orderNbr.IsEqual<P.AsString>
                           .And<POOrder.orderType.IsEqual<P.AsString>>>
                    .View.Select(Base, receipt.OrigPONbr, receipt.POType);

    if (order == null) return;

    // Get the extensions for the related POOrder and current POReceipt
    POOrderExt orderExt = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(order);
    POReceiptExt receiptExt = PXCache<POReceipt>.GetExtension<POReceiptExt>(receipt);

    if (orderExt != null && receiptExt != null)
    {
        // Map custom fields from POOrderExt to POReceiptExt
        receiptExt.UsrCallForShipment = orderExt.UsrCallForShipment;
        receiptExt.UsrConfirmedOnBoard = orderExt.UsrConfirmedOnBoard;
        receiptExt.UsrContainerNo = orderExt.UsrContainerNo;
        receiptExt.UsrEstArrivalDate = orderExt.UsrEstArrivalDate;
        receiptExt.UsrOrderType = orderExt.UsrOrderType;
        receiptExt.UsrStatus = orderExt.UsrStatus;

        // Persist changes to the POReceipt record
        Base.Caches<POReceipt>().Update(receipt);
    }
}

    #endregion
  }
  }


I also tried to directly insert copying in the DAC but his does not work either
[PXDBBool]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<POOrderExt.usrConfirmedOnBoard,
            Where<POOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<POReceipt.pOType>>,
            And<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.origPONbr>>>>>),
            PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]

[PXUIField(DisplayName="Confirmed On Board")]

